# Place text over image top left, with percentage top and left offsets

Tags: html, css

I've got the following piece of code and would like to place the text `#top-left` over the image top left, with offsets of 20% relative to the parent of the image: the div `#container`. What happens, instead, is that the text is offsetted 20% relative to the body. How do I fix that? And maybe, how would I make the text 10% of the height of the image?

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#top-left {
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    font-size: 5pt;
}

#img {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="top-left">Vincent Van Gogh - Wheatfield with Crows</div>
    <img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Vincent_van_Gogh_%281853-1890%29_-_Wheat_Field_with_Crows_%281890%29.jpg/320px-Vincent_van_Gogh_%281853-1890%29_-_Wheat_Field_with_Crows_%281890%29.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh - Wheatfield with Crows"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shrink-wrap the container to the size of the image **first**.

You could use any appropriate kind of `display` method, `inline-block / inline-flex / inline-grid` etc.. or `float:left` to shrink the container to the size of the image.

```css
#container {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

#top-left {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   left: 20%;
   color: White;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="top-left">Vincent Van Gogh - Wheatfield with Crows</div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Vincent_van_Gogh_%281853-1890%29_-_Wheat_Field_with_Crows_%281890%29.jpg/320px-Vincent_van_Gogh_%281853-1890%29_-_Wheat_Field_with_Crows_%281890%29.jpg" alt="Vincent Van Gogh - Wheatfield with Crows"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect but... I forgot to mention (now fixed in the original question) that my img has the width attribute, and that breaks the behavior

Comment: Then it's not possible, If you want to overlay the image it needs it's own container. so that the % can be calculated correctly

Comment: So I should insert that single img in another container (which itself is inside `#container`)?